# ActiveDocument.Printout issue

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have two word documents, source and target. My target document is pulling values from a table inside source document and putting those concatenated values stored inside a variable named **ReportHeader** into it's page header. I have used two For-Next loops, the outer loops takes care of designated rows inside source document and this loop begins at 6th row till count of total rows inside that table.

My inner loop named "For xPages = 1 To numPages" takes care of number of parges required for each Annexure that it finds inside the table and loops through found number of pages for a particular Annexure reference.

Below is reference screenshot of my table. Please ignore the fact the few preceding lines of my tableare not being shown here. My business begins with 6th row that shows Annexure A.

[image]

Everything works fine as long as I test values in Debug.print or Msgbox but when I sent these values for printing using **ActiveDocument.PrintOut**, I notice an abnormal printing behaviour. First few rows starting at row 6 of table are ignored and later not all the pages are sent to printing.

Any feedback from you guys would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Syed

```
        Sub PrintMyHeaders()
        Dim r As Range
        Dim sourceDoc, jobNumber, AnnexureRaw, Annexure, ReportHeader As String
        Dim numPages As Integer
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        jobNumber = InputBox("Enter job number")

        sourceDoc = ActiveDocument.Name

        ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers
        Set r = ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Range

        For Each doc In Documents
            If doc.Name = "Template.doc" Then Found = True

            Next doc

            If Found <> True Then
                Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Users\smi\Documents\Template.doc"
            Else
                Documents("Template.doc").Activate
            End If

        Documents(sourceDoc).Activate

        For i = 6 To r.Rows.Count

            AnnexureRaw = Replace(r.Rows(i).Cells(2).Range.Text, "", "")
            Annexure = Replace(AnnexureRaw, Chr(13), "")

            numPages = Val(r.Rows(i).Cells(3).Range.Text)


                For xPages = 1 To numPages
                     counter = counter + 1
                     ReportHeader = "PAGE " & xPages & " OF " & numPages & vbCrLf _
                     & "OUR REF: TKU-" & jobNumber & "/2018" & vbCrLf _
                     & "ANNEXURE : " & Chr(34) & Annexure & Chr(34)


                     Documents("Template.doc").Activate


                     If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
                         ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
                     End If

                If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
                    ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
                    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
                End If

                    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader

                    Selection.Font.Name = "Arial"
                    Selection.Font.Size = 8
                    Selection.Font.Bold = True
                    Selection.Text = ReportHeader
                    Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly
                    Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 6
                    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight


                    ActiveDocument.PrintOut
                    'Debug.Print ReportHeader & vbCrLf

                    Documents(sourceDoc).Activate

                Next xPages

        Next

        Documents("template.doc").Activate
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        Documents(sourceDoc).Activate

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End Sub
```

Comment: What's the setting of the option "Print in background"? (File/Options/Advanced, section "Print") If that's activated try de-activating it and see if the behavior is different.

Comment: Note that the code would benefit from a number of optimizations. But before suggestions could be made it would be helpful to know why and what is being printed out in each loop (instead of waiting until the code has finished processing the table).

Comment: Hi Cindy, Thanks again. I just checked and noticed that the "Print in background" option was checked. With regards to your second question, the only reason I am using printout command before letting the loop to read all the rows of source table is because the values are being printed in header area. Otherwise, I would have stored all the values in an array and printed them on each new page in the body section of the document, and in our case the body or main part of each annexure is not at our disposal to print our required annexure info, instead these are pre-printed supporting documents.

Comment: The target document is just a placeholder where we are placing info for printing about each annexure in header area at runtime and sending printout command to printer. Assume you have put a stack of all the annexures on printer so that through this small program you could print 3 lines of basic info on top right side where you have some space to add this info.

Comment: Just to let you know, I have been getting this job done using mail merge but that method takes around 10-15 mins in setting up my Excel based source data each time. And I have to work between 2 different apps, Word and Excel. If I manage to fix my printing problem as I have briefed about earlier, I would be able to save 10-15 mins and the job could be completed in one click only.

Comment: «I have been getting this job done using mail merge but that method takes around 10-15 mins in setting up my Excel based source data each time». You should only ever need to do a mailmerge setup once, then save the mailmerge main document. From then on, it's just a matter of opening the mailmerge main document and executing the merge, which requires just a couple of mouse clicks, even if the data file is an entirely new one with the same name.

Comment: This is not a usual setup of fixed source data that you print time and again. In this case we have to put source data in Excel file every time because it changes every time. Actually, I am more interested in finding a solution to the printing issue I am having at the moment.

Comment: Cindy, Something good has happened. Turning "Print in background" to off has solved my printing problem and now it is printing all the rows in exact order without missing any of the rows data from the table in source document. You did mention that the code can still be optimized though, so I would like to hear from you on this soon. By the way, please ignore that "counter = counter + 1" which I added at one point just to check something. Other than that, each and every line was intended to get the desired output. Thank you very much for your tip.

Comment: I would also like to thank Macropod for taking his time and adding a useful tip.

Answer (score 1):

When printing out documents in relatively quick succession, things can get "mixed up" if background printing is turned on. This is an option in Word:

```
File/Options/Advanced, section "Print"
```

In the object model, to turn it off programmatically you can use the following. If the user likes having it turned on, save the current setting, turn it off, then restore the setting at the end of the code:

```
Options.PrintBackground = False
```

Since speed of execution is a concern, your code can be optimized. The following suggestions can also help to make it more self-documenting. Note that I'm not testing, just writing from the top of my head, so I may make a typo or two...

1. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code modules. This will save you from frustrating error messages if you mistype a variable name.
2. Use declared objects throughout. Referring back to `ActiveDocument` each time is less efficient (VBA has to figure out which it is, every time. Also, the active document *could* change during code execution, which would mess things up.) Ditto for repeatedly requesting `Tables(3)`.
3. If your concern when looping a collection is to ensure a certain member is present (a particular document, in your case) you can use `Exit For` to break off the loop before all members have been queried.
4. It's not necessary to activate a document in order to work with it in code. Once you have `Document` objects, that's all you need.
5. It's also not necessary to fiddle with the Views in order to work with a header or footer. I've deleted those lines.

I hope I've kept "everything straight"!

```
  Option Explicit

  Sub PrintMyHeaders()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim sourceDoc, jobNumber, AnnexureRaw, Annexure, ReportHeader As String
    Dim numPages As Integer
    Dim sourceTable as Word.Table, doc as Word.Document
    Dim tDoc as Word.Document

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    jobNumber = InputBox("Enter job number")

    Set sourceDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set sourceTable = sourceDoc.Tables(3)
    sourceTable.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers
    Set r = sourceTable.Range

    For Each doc In Documents
        If doc.Name = "Template.doc" Then 
          Found = True
          Exit For
        End If
    Next doc

    If Found <> True Then
        Set tDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\smi\Documents\Template.doc")
    Else
        Set tDoc = Documents("Template.doc")
    End If

    For i = 6 To r.Rows.Count

        AnnexureRaw = Replace(r.Rows(i).Cells(2).Range.Text, "", "")
        Annexure = Replace(AnnexureRaw, Chr(13), "")

        numPages = Val(r.Rows(i).Cells(3).Range.Text)

            For xPages = 1 To numPages
                 counter = counter + 1
                 ReportHeader = "PAGE " & xPages & " OF " & numPages & vbCrLf _
                 & "OUR REF: TKU-" & jobNumber & "/2018" & vbCrLf _
                 & "ANNEXURE : " & Chr(34) & Annexure & Chr(34)

                 Dim rngHeader as Word.Range
                 Set rngHeader = tDoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
                rngHeader.Font.Name = "Arial"
                rngHeader.Font.Size = 8
                rngHeader.Font.Bold = True
                rngHeader.Text = ReportHeader
                rngHeader.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly
                rngHeader.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 6
                rngHeader.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight

                tDoc.PrintOut
                'Debug.Print ReportHeader & vbCrLf
            Next xPages
    Next

    tDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Cindy. I am gonna give it a try and I am sure the changes you have made will make it more efficient code for my purposes. You have also shared some worthwhile techniques which I am sure if taken into consideration right at the beginning of writing such procedures, will help a great deal.